# HTML img src not working in subfolder of subfolder

Tags: html

I'm pretty new to HTML and I'm trying to add some images to my page. Images are located in  a subfolder , but two subfolders won't work:

```
 <img id="lungIcon" src="icon/red/001-medical.svg">
 <img id="liverIcon" src="icon/003-human-liver.svg">
```

liverIcon is show, but lungIcon not. red is a subfolder of icon and my editor (WebStorm) even autofills the src of lungIcon because it can find the file.

[Inside the icon folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqsXN.png)

As you can see red is inside icon. red contains the same files as icon but in a different color. Why won't lungIcon.svg display?

Comment: check your networks tab and see which path is browser actually hitting for your files

Comment: can you post your folder structure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using relative path (`./your/path/to/img) eg:

```
 <img id="lungIcon" src="./icon/red/001-medical.svg">
<img id="liverIcon" src="./icon/003-human-liver.svg">
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. At first I thought it didn't but it turned out I had also corrupted the svg file. Oops.

Comment: It's weird that one icon was working before the fix. If the relative path syntax for both sources was wrong originally. Hmm..

Answer (score 1):

Or try using full path. like `src="/images/icon.svg"`, that's how I do mine.